# How do we handle questions that are different but could be solved by the same answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

What to do when there are two *different* questions but they can be solved with the same answer (such as "What is 3 + 1" and "What is 2 + 2")?

Look at this question:

[Icons from my Home Directory in 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507882/icons-from-my-home-directory-in-23-10/1507888#1507888)

Now observe this one:

[All folders visible in desktop linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507849/all-folders-visible-in-desktop-linux/1507891#1507891)

I have answered the first question and was about to answer the second but caught myself on the thought that I was basically saying the same thing as in the first answer.

What do we do in this case? The questions *are not* duplicates but can be solved in the same way. Would we *still* flag one of the posts as duplicate of the other (because the solutions are are the same)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When deciding whether to flag or vote to close a question as duplicate, I ask this question:

**Could a useful answer to this question exist that would not make sense if posted to the proposed target?**

If the answer is yes, then don't close, because closing shuts down the potential for useful answers.

I also agree with people who say this another way: that it's not enough for the target to have an answer that could work for the proposed dupe question; the question itself must be the same.

After all, our goal is not to close as many questions as possible or to have as few questions as possible!

Comment: +1, you should send that memo to SO mods, who instead delete such answers ([example of an answer deleted by SO mods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32918798/395857). Needs +10k rep to see, but I copied it on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267319/178179).

Answer (score 5):

### "YES and NO"

Are valid answers to many questions in life.

So are **"TRUE"** and **"FALSE"**.

**"Check to make sure the computer is plugged in"** may be a valid answer to many Ubuntu questions.

If the answer suits the question and is valid, it is the right answer.